# I'm Trying To Make Football Manager Play On Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wine

Whenever i run Football Manager through the terminal I get a whole lot of stuff written in it HELP !!!

```
ephraim@miarhpe:~/Downloads/Football Manager$ wine fm.exe
001a:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142
002a:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0040:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
wine: configuration in L"/home/ephraim/.wine" has been updated.
wine: Unhandled page fault on write access to 000000014D3D4FCA at address 000000014BF26A07 (thread 0053), starting debugger...
0053:err:seh:call_stack_handlers invalid frame 7d0db458 (0x132000-0x230000)
Unhandled exception: page fault on write access to 0x14d3d4fca, invalid program stack in 64-bit code (0x000000014bf26a07).
Register dump:
 rip:000000014bf26a07 rsp:000000000022ebf8 rbp:ffffffffe11874dd eflags:00010202 (  R- --  I   - - - )
 rax:0000000000000000 rbx:ffffffffce1f3519 rcx:ffffffff6651cbc2 rdx:ffffffffffffffff
 rsi:000000000022edb0 rdi:000000000022f610  r8:00000000d238a593  r9:000000014e8fa045 r10:0000000000000000
 r11:0000000041be0917 r12:0000000000000000 r13:ffffffff855c0805 r14:0000000000000000 r15:0000000000000001
Stack dump:
0x000000000022ebf8:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000000022ec08:  0000000000000002 00007ffda2393308
0x000000000022ec18:  00007ffda2393320 000000007d1c3150
0x000000000022ec28:  00007fc3bc514c91 0000000000000000
0x000000000022ec38:  000000000022ef90 000000000022ee30
0x000000000022ec48:  fffffffffffffff8 0000000000000001
0x000000000022ec58:  0000000000000005 000000007d1c3150
0x000000000022ec68:  00007fc3bc28f785 0000000000000000
0x000000000022ec78:  000000000022ee70 00007fc3bc5182c0
0x000000000022ec88:  000000000022ede0 0000000600000000
0x000000000022ec98:  0000000000000000 000000000022ed50
0x000000000022eca8:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x000000014bf26a07 in fm (+0xbf26a07) (0xffffffffe11874dd)
0x000000014bf26a07: lock cmpxchgl   %r15d,0x00000000014ae5ba(%rip)
Modules:
Module  Address                 Debug info  Name (155 modules)
PE            230000-          3f8000   Deferred        icuuc59
PE            400000-          53b000   Deferred        steam_api64
PE            540000-          726000   Deferred        vpxmt
PE          4a900000-        4ab57000   Deferred        icuin59
PE          4ad00000-        4ad03000   Deferred        icudt59
ELF         7b000000-        7b0e2000   Deferred        kernelbase<elf>
  \-PE          7b010000-        7b0e2000   \               kernelbase
ELF         7b400000-        7b68b000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE          7b420000-        7b68b000   \               kernel32
ELF         7bc00000-        7befb000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE          7bc20000-        7befb000   \               ntdll
ELF         7c000000-        7c005000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
PE         140000000-       157b86000   Export          fm
PE         180000000-       18017d000   Deferred        openal32
ELF     7fc3b7d25000-    7fc3b7d3b000   Deferred        api-ms-win-security-systemfunctions-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b7d30000-    7fc3b7d3b000   \               api-ms-win-security-systemfunctions-l1-1-0
ELF     7fc3b7d3b000-    7fc3b7d51000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-obsolete-l1-2-0<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b7d40000-    7fc3b7d51000   \               api-ms-win-core-localization-obsolete-l1-2-0
ELF     7fc3b7d51000-    7fc3b7d67000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-1<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b7d60000-    7fc3b7d67000   \               api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-1
ELF     7fc3b7d67000-    7fc3b7d7d000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b7d70000-    7fc3b7d7d000   \               api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0
ELF     7fc3b7d7d000-    7fc3b7dae000   Deferred        msvfw32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b7d80000-    7fc3b7dae000   \               msvfw32
ELF     7fc3b7dae000-    7fc3b7e02000   Deferred        avifil32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b7dc0000-    7fc3b7e02000   \               avifil32
ELF     7fc3b7e02000-    7fc3b7e19000   Deferred        avicap32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b7e10000-    7fc3b7e19000   \               avicap32
ELF     7fc3b7e19000-    7fc3b7e2f000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b7e20000-    7fc3b7e2f000   \               api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1
ELF     7fc3b7e2f000-    7fc3b7e45000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b7e40000-    7fc3b7e45000   \               api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
ELF     7fc3b7e45000-    7fc3b7e68000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF     7fc3b7e68000-    7fc3b7f86000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF     7fc3b7f86000-    7fc3b7fa7000   Deferred        liblz4.so.1
ELF     7fc3b7fa7000-    7fc3b7fb3000   Deferred        libffi.so.7
ELF     7fc3b7fb3000-    7fc3b8060000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF     7fc3b8060000-    7fc3b807c000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF     7fc3b807c000-    7fc3b8083000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF     7fc3b8083000-    7fc3b8107000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF     7fc3b8107000-    7fc3b813f000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.5
ELF     7fc3b813f000-    7fc3b8179000   Deferred        libnettle.so.7
ELF     7fc3b8179000-    7fc3b818f000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF     7fc3b818f000-    7fc3b8311000   Deferred        libunistring.so.2
ELF     7fc3b8311000-    7fc3b8332000   Deferred        libidn2.so.0
ELF     7fc3b8332000-    7fc3b8468000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF     7fc3b8468000-    7fc3b84b9000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF     7fc3b84b9000-    7fc3b84c8000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF     7fc3b84c8000-    7fc3b84f9000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF     7fc3b84f9000-    7fc3b85d6000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF     7fc3b85d6000-    7fc3b87ac000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF     7fc3b87ac000-    7fc3b87bf000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF     7fc3b87bf000-    7fc3b880c000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF     7fc3b880c000-    7fc3b88a7000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF     7fc3b88ae000-    7fc3b88c4000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b88b0000-    7fc3b88c4000   \               api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
ELF     7fc3b88c4000-    7fc3b8904000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b88d0000-    7fc3b8904000   \               uxtheme
ELF     7fc3b8904000-    7fc3b890c000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF     7fc3b890c000-    7fc3b8919000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF     7fc3b8919000-    7fc3b892b000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF     7fc3b892b000-    7fc3b8930000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF     7fc3b8930000-    7fc3b893d000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF     7fc3b893d000-    7fc3b8b47000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF     7fc3b8b47000-    7fc3b8b4e000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF     7fc3b8b4e000-    7fc3b8b53000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF     7fc3b8b53000-    7fc3b8bde000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b8b60000-    7fc3b8bde000   \               setupapi
ELF     7fc3b8bde000-    7fc3b8bf8000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF     7fc3b8bf8000-    7fc3b8c00000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF     7fc3b8c00000-    7fc3b8c06000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF     7fc3b8c06000-    7fc3b8c30000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF     7fc3b8c30000-    7fc3b8d6d000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF     7fc3b8d6d000-    7fc3b8d82000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF     7fc3b8d88000-    7fc3b8d8f000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF     7fc3b8d8f000-    7fc3b8d9d000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF     7fc3b8d9f000-    7fc3b8e68000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b8db0000-    7fc3b8e68000   \               winex11
ELF     7fc3b8f0a000-    7fc3b8f13000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF     7fc3b8f13000-    7fc3b8f41000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF     7fc3b8f41000-    7fc3b8f88000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF     7fc3b8f88000-    7fc3b8fc0000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF     7fc3b8fc0000-    7fc3b907f000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF     7fc3b907f000-    7fc3b90af000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.6
ELF     7fc3b90af000-    7fc3b90d8000   Deferred        libncurses.so.6
ELF     7fc3b90f5000-    7fc3b910e000   Deferred        xinput9_1_0<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9100000-    7fc3b910e000   \               xinput9_1_0
ELF     7fc3b910e000-    7fc3b9128000   Deferred        wtsapi32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9120000-    7fc3b9128000   \               wtsapi32
ELF     7fc3b9128000-    7fc3b9157000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9130000-    7fc3b9157000   \               mpr
ELF     7fc3b9157000-    7fc3b920a000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9160000-    7fc3b920a000   \               wininet
ELF     7fc3b920a000-    7fc3b924f000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9210000-    7fc3b924f000   \               ws2_32
ELF     7fc3b924f000-    7fc3b9283000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9260000-    7fc3b9283000   \               iphlpapi
ELF     7fc3b9283000-    7fc3b928e000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF     7fc3b9295000-    7fc3b92b5000   Deferred        pdh<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b92a0000-    7fc3b92b5000   \               pdh
ELF     7fc3b92b5000-    7fc3b92e5000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b92c0000-    7fc3b92e5000   \               msacm32
ELF     7fc3b92e5000-    7fc3b93ae000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b92f0000-    7fc3b93ae000   \               winmm
ELF     7fc3b93ae000-    7fc3b9508000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b93d0000-    7fc3b9508000   \               oleaut32
ELF     7fc3b9508000-    7fc3b9524000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF     7fc3b9528000-    7fc3b9541000   Deferred        powrprof<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9530000-    7fc3b9541000   \               powrprof
ELF     7fc3b9541000-    7fc3b95cf000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9550000-    7fc3b95cf000   \               dbghelp
ELF     7fc3b95cf000-    7fc3b95f6000   Deferred        bcrypt<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b95e0000-    7fc3b95f6000   \               bcrypt
ELF     7fc3b95f6000-    7fc3b9709000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9600000-    7fc3b9709000   \               crypt32
ELF     7fc3b9709000-    7fc3b976b000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9710000-    7fc3b976b000   \               winspool
ELF     7fc3b976b000-    7fc3b9791000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9770000-    7fc3b9791000   \               imm32
ELF     7fc3b9791000-    7fc3b97e3000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b97a0000-    7fc3b97e3000   \               usp10
ELF     7fc3b97e3000-    7fc3b996a000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b97f0000-    7fc3b996a000   \               comctl32
ELF     7fc3b996a000-    7fc3b9a01000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9980000-    7fc3b9a01000   \               rpcrt4
ELF     7fc3b9a01000-    7fc3b9b75000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9a30000-    7fc3b9b75000   \               ole32
ELF     7fc3b9b75000-    7fc3b9b9b000   Deferred        shcore<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9b80000-    7fc3b9b9b000   \               shcore
ELF     7fc3b9b9b000-    7fc3b9c92000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9bc0000-    7fc3b9c92000   \               msvcrt
ELF     7fc3b9c92000-    7fc3b9e4a000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9cb0000-    7fc3b9e4a000   \               gdi32
ELF     7fc3b9e4a000-    7fc3ba0e5000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3b9e70000-    7fc3ba0e5000   \               user32
ELF     7fc3ba0e5000-    7fc3ba14d000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3ba0f0000-    7fc3ba14d000   \               shlwapi
ELF     7fc3ba14d000-    7fc3baba7000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3ba170000-    7fc3baba7000   \               shell32
ELF     7fc3baba7000-    7fc3bace7000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3babb0000-    7fc3bace7000   \               comdlg32
ELF     7fc3bade7000-    7fc3bae84000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3bae00000-    7fc3bae84000   \               advapi32
ELF     7fc3baf84000-    7fc3baf98000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF     7fc3bbf76000-    7fc3bbf9d000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF     7fc3bbf9d000-    7fc3bbfb8000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF     7fc3bbfb8000-    7fc3bc107000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF     7fc3bc107000-    7fc3bc124000   Deferred        libunwind.so.8
ELF     7fc3bc126000-    7fc3bc12c000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF     7fc3bc12c000-    7fc3bc31e000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF     7fc3bc31e000-    7fc3bc341000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF     7fc3bc346000-    7fc3bc35e000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE      7fc3bc350000-    7fc3bc35e000   \               version
ELF     7fc3bc35e000-    7fc3bc501000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF     7fc3bc503000-    7fc3bc533000   Deferred        ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000022    0
    00000019    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 plugplay.exe
    00000016    0
    00000015    0
    00000012    0
00000017 winedevice.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001c    0
    0000001b    0
    0000001a    0
    00000018    0
00000020 winedevice.exe
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
    00000023    0
    00000021    0
00000052 (D) Z:\home\ephraim\Downloads\Football Manager\fm.exe
    00000053    0 <==
00000054 explorer.exe
    00000058    0
    00000057    0
    00000056    0
    00000055    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)
    Platform: x86_64
    Version: Windows 10
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 5.4.0-42-generic
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxrz5.png

Comment: By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals. to see your text. Rather, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the `{}` formatting tool.

Comment: @waltinator check it out

Comment: What does `file fm.exe` show?

Comment: `ephraim@miarhpe:~/Downloads/Football Manager$ file fm.exe
fm.exe: PE32+ executable (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows` @waltinator

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should Edit your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Have you checked winehq.org ? Is your program known to work (or not work) on that website?